# Easiest way for crypto illiterate web consumers to buy Monero to spend at website

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mymonero

If you offer payment in Monero at your website the average consumer who doesn't use cryptocurencies may ask you how to buy it in the simpliest way. For people not used to crypto looking at the different crypto exchanges is pretty intimidating.

I know there are many different ways and exchanges but can anyone recommend (preferably from experiece) a simple exchange or method for UK (pounds sterling currency users) I could recommend to web customers? This is for people who know absolutely nothing about crypto and who are used to Paypal or Credit card? 
They expect to go somewhere with a GBP credit card and buy monero. I want to recommend somewhere as easy as possible.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

"simplest way" <- perhaps point them to purchase Monero at a big exchange like Binance or Kraken. But, for a complete novice, even that will be daunting, that's just where we're at right now on the adoption / general knowledge curve of cryptocurrencies.

The sphere of learning about cryptocurrencies is vast, so if you want people to learn, why not create resources for them.

And as a seller, you could implement your own conversion of card to Monero or use a third party integration like Globee.

It really depends what your goal is; making the purchase easy or educating.

Comment: Thanks, @jtgrassie, making the purchase easy would be the goal. Thanks for the tips.